# Why is the word "branch" used in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology, math-history

In complex analysis the term *branch* is used to designate a holomorphic function defined on a region. The most prominent example is the principal logarithm, which is a branch of the logarithm.

Does anybody know the history of why the word *branch* used?

I'm guessing *branch, tree, decisions, choice.*

Comment: Did you check Riemann's dissertation? Also, history of math and science stack exchange will be a better place for the question (Alex Eremenko is likely to anwer).

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MoisheKohan err... of course I didn't read that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riemann introduced the term in his paper "Theory of Abelian Functions" ("Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen", Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, vol. 54. pp.101–155. 1857). After discussing the analytic continuation of $\log(x-a)$ around the point $a$, with the change of value $2\pi i$, he writes:

> It is convenient to designate the different continuations of *one* function into the same part of the $z$-plane, *branches* of this function, and to call a point, around which a branch of a function continues into another, a *branch point* of the function. Where no branch takes place, the function is called *single-valued* or *monodromic*.
>
> Zur bequemeren Bezeichnung dieser Verhältnisse sollen die verschiedenen
> Fortsetzungen *einer* Function für denselben Theil der $z$-Ebene *Zweige* dieser
> Function genannt werden und ein Punkt, um welchen sich ein Zweig einer Function in einen andern fortsetzt, eine *Verzweigungsstelle* dieser Function; wo keine Verzweigung stattfindet, heisst die Function *einändrig* oder *monodrom*.

In his doctoral thesis, there is a single occurrence of the term "branch" ("Zweig"), in the compound word "branch point" ("Zweigepunkt"). The term is not defined. However, the concept occurs earlier, where it is called a "winding point" ("Windungspunkt"). Riemann has already introduced his notion of a multiple-sheeted covering of a part of the complex plane. He discusses the situation where one returns to the same sheet of the covering surface after $m$ circuits around a point $\sigma$. He then writes:

> The point circling $\sigma$ then returns to the same surface segment after every $m$ circuits and is limited to $m$ of the surface segments lying over each other, which are joined by a single point above $\sigma$. We call this point a winding point of order $(m-1)$ of the surface $T$.
>
> Der um $\sigma$ sich bewegende Punkt kommt alsdann nach je $m$ Umläufen in denselben Flächentheil zurück und ist auf $m$ der auf einander liegenden Flächentheile eingeschränkt, welche sich über $\sigma$ zu einem einzigen Punkte vereinigen. Wir nennen diesen Punkt einen Windungspunkt $(m-1)$ter Ordnung der
> Fläche $T$.

While Riemann doesn't provide an explanation for the term "branch", I think the term "branch point" has a pretty intuitive signficance: several parts of the surface "branch out" from the branch point.